# Function to generate 2D array with random, non repeating numbers with range of 99

Tags: c#, arrays, random

I need to create a function which generates a 2D array of random non repeating numbers with a predefined range of 1 - 99.

```
static Random RandomGenerator = new Random();

int[][] ran_array ={ 
    new int [10],
    new int [10],
    new int [10] 
};
```

I was thinking of using 2 loops within a function to  go through each array, and then each list within the array to add in the numbers, so the output would look something like this

```
static Random RandomGenerator = new Random();

int[][] ran_array ={ 
    new int [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 7, 9, 10],
    new int [23, 24, 12, 53, 75, 87, 20, 12, 25, 11],
    new int [11, 54, 74, 67, 32, 87, 23, 98, 31, 1] 
};
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. Have you tried that approach you've described? Have you faced some problem when tried it?

Comment: Should numbers be unique within the 2D array or just within each of its lines? Should the result array be jugged one i.e. `int[][] result` or *2d* one i.e. `int[,]  result`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this method:

```
static Random RandomGenerator = new Random();

public static int[][] GetRandomArray(int size1, int size2, int minValue, int maxValue, bool uniqueValues = false) 
{
    int[][] ran_array = new int[size1][];
    for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++)
    {
        ran_array[i] = new int[size2];
        HashSet<int> set = new HashSet<int>();
        for (int ii = 0; ii < size2; ii++)
        {
            int nextValue = RandomGenerator.Next(minValue, maxValue);
            if (uniqueValues)
            {
                while (!set.Add(nextValue))
                    nextValue = RandomGenerator.Next(minValue, maxValue);
            }
            ran_array[i][ii] = nextValue;
        }
    }
    return ran_array;
}
```

Your samples suggest that you want this:

```
int[][] ran_array = GetRandomArray(3, 10, 1, 100, true);
```

Comment: Usually random + non repeating + defined range points to "create a list of all possible values and randomly select (and remove) one after the other until you have enough (or ran out of values)".

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution to generate a random set of numbers in a 3 x 10 array:

```
Random rand = new Random();
var availableNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 99).ToList();
var result = new int[3,10];

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        result[i,j] = availableNumbers
                       .Skip(rand.Next(0, availableNumbers.Count()))
                       .First();

        // Remove used numbers to avoid duplicates:
        availableNumbers.Remove(result[i,j]);
    }
}
```

Perhaps not the most efficient solution, but it works, and is fairly simple.